# DictReader is not parsing my string in the right way

Tags: python

I'm reading a file from AWS:

```
file_content = s3_resource.Object(BUCKET_NAME, filename).get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
```

And as result file_content is a string in the format:

```
"CPF;TIPO;CONTATO;PRODUTO\n11111111111;phone;111111111;aaa\n22222222222;phone;22222222222;bbb,ccc\n33333333333;email;xxxxx@gmail.com;ddd"
```

Then I try:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(io.StringIO(file_content), delimiter=";")
```

But reader don't became a dictionary:

```
for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

print do reader:

[image: print do reader]

Try do this:

```
for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

Result:

```
    for row in reader:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/csv.py", line 110, in __next__
    self.fieldnames
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/csv.py", line 97, in fieldnames
    self._fieldnames = next(self.reader)
_csv.Error: line contains NUL
```

Comment: `reader` isn't supposed be be a dictionary, it's supposed to be a DictReader. `row` is, which it seems to be. Here is your code working just fine: https://repl.it/@alexmojaki/UnkemptMuddyActionscript#main.py Please explain what the problem is and provide some non-working code that doesn't involve the PyCharm debugger.